# Getting this ONNXRuntimeError again and again. Please suggest

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run this code to remove background from my image but I keep getting an error. Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
from rembg.bg import remove
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image

input_path = 'crop.jpeg'
output_path = 'out.png'

f = np.fromfile(input_path)
result = remove(f)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(result)).convert("RGBA")
img.save(output_path)
```

```
*C:\Sauhard\Internships\TEST IMAGES>python -u "c:\Sauhard\Internships\TEST IMAGES\a.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Sauhard\Internships\TEST IMAGES\a.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = remove(f)
  File "C:\Users\Sauhard Saini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\bg.py", line 133, in remove
    session = new_session("u2net")
  File "C:\Users\Sauhard Saini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rembg\session_factory.py", line 60, in new_session
    ort.InferenceSession(
  File "C:\Users\Sauhard Saini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
  File "C:\Users\Sauhard Saini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 395, in _create_inference_session
    sess.initialize_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
RuntimeError: D:\a\_work\1\s\onnxruntime\core\session\provider_bridge_ort.cc:1029 onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : LoadLibrary failed with error 126 "" when trying to load "C:\Users\Sauhard Saini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_providers_tensorrt.dll"*
```

Comment: This is most likely due to your graphics driver or some faulty configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the generic graphics card driver provided with the  Windows installation and happens mainly with AMD/ATI based solutions.

download and install the latest available version of the graphics card driver for your hardware at [www.amd.com](http://www.amd.com)

Another option can be the installation of the "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio".